# Least-squares in integral form

Tags: integration, least-squares

In the linear least squares problem one minimizes the norm of the residual vector:
$$
\chi^2=\|\vec{b}-A\vec{x}\|_2^2=\sum_i^m{|b_i-\sum_j^nA_{ij}x_j|^2}
$$
where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}, \vec{b}\in \mathbb{R}^{m}, \vec{x}\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$.

The solution to the problem has to satisfy normal equations:
$$
A^\top A\vec{x}=A^{\top}\vec{b}
$$

However how does the least square problem look like in the general case of an arbitrary operator A?
In particular, how do the operators $A^\dagger$ and $A^{\dagger}A$ look like in case of integral operator:
$$
A: x(r) \rightarrow \int{a(R,r)x(r)dr}
$$

Answer (score 1):

I found that the textbook on Advanced Linear Algebra by Steven Roman [1](http://ksu.edu.sa/sites/py/ar/mpy/departments/math/learnResources/ResourceCenter/Documents/Advanced%20Linear%20Algebra%20-%20Steven%20Roman.pdf) on pages 433-434 gives an answer that I was looking for:

For an arbitrary operator $A$ the normal equation still looks the same except the transpose of $A$ is changed to the adjoint of $A$:
$$
A^{\dagger}Ax=A^{\dagger}b
$$

To find the $A^{\dagger}$ for an integral operator $A$ we can use the definition of the adjoint operator:
$$
\langle Ax,y\rangle=\langle x,A^{\dagger}y\rangle=\int {dR \left( \int a(R,r)x(r)dr\right)y^*(R) }=\int dr\left( \int a^*(R,r)y(R)dR\right)^*x(r)
$$
Then
$$
A^{\dagger}x=\int{a^*(R,r)x(R)dR}
$$
$$
A^{\dagger}Ax=\int{\int{a^*(R,r')a(R,r)x(r)}dr}
$$